# canvas is null and canvas.getContext is not a function

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am busy working through this [tutorial](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Games/Tutorials/2D_Breakout_game_pure_JavaScript) in which a 2D game is created using Javascript and the canvas element and I am having trouble with two errors.

My initial code was this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Game Canvas Workshop</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            *{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            canvas {
                background: #eee;
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id"myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas> 

        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="../game.js"></script> -->
        <script>

            //var test = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
            //console.log(test);

            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            console.log(ctx);


                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.rect(20, 40, 50, 50);
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();

        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

When I try to grab the canvas element using `document.getElementById` it returns the error: `canvas is null`

So I changed the code to get the canvas element using `document.getElementsByTagName` and then wrote a test to print the result to the console and it returned the element.

But then when I try to use `canvas.getContext("2d")` I get the following error: `canvas.getContext("2d") is not a function`

I've read most of the answers to similar queries and tried them out with my code but they don't seem to work for me.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is here (missing "=" )

```
<canvas id"myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

Change to:

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

Full code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <title>Game Canvas Workshop</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            *{
                padding: 0;
                margin: 0;
            }

            canvas {
                background: #eee;
                display: block;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas> 

        <!-- <script type="text/javascript" src="../game.js"></script> -->
        <script>

            //var test = document.getElementsByTagName("canvas");
            //console.log(test);

            var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

            var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
            console.log(ctx);


                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.rect(20, 40, 50, 50);
                ctx.fill();
                ctx.closePath();

        </script>
    </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks man. I'm such an idiot. I was wracking my brain and it was a missing "=" that did me in.

Comment: No problem, You are just starting to learn JavaScript. Good luck :).

Answer (score 0):

You need

```
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
          ^
```

an assignment for the id.

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById("myCanvas");

var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
//console.log(ctx);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.rect(20, 40, 50, 50);
ctx.fill();
ctx.closePath();
```

```css
* { padding: 0; margin: 0; }
canvas { background: #eee; display: block; margin: 0 auto; }
```

```html
<canvas id="myCanvas" width="480" height="320"></canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 Please load your <script> after <body>. then this would work.
 <body>
 <input type="text" id="myInput" >
 <canvas id="myCanvas" width="200" height="100"></canvas>
 </body>
 <script>
 var c = document.getElementById("myCanvas");
 var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
 </script>
```